# each and string index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array with both integer and string index.

For some reason, it seems that $.each does not correctly iterate over the string indexes.

The below output is:

idx: 0
1
2
3

idx: 1
4
5
6

idx: 2
7
8
9

// actual
idx: 3
a
b
c

// expected
idx: abc
10
11
12

Here is the code I tested with:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery - each</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var a = new Array();
            a.push(0);
            a[0] = [1, 2, 3];

            a.push(1);
            a[1] = [4, 5, 6];

            a.push(2);
            a[2] = [7, 8, 9];

            a.push("abc");
            a["abc"] = [10, 11, 12];

            $.each(a, function (idx, v) {

                alert("idx: " + idx);
                alert(v[0]);
                alert(v[1]);
                alert(v[2]);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Thank you very much for your help,

Richard Hughes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var a = {};
        a['0'] = [1, 2, 3];
        a['1'] = [4, 5, 6];
        a['2'] = [7, 8, 9];
        a['abc'] = [10, 11, 12];

        $.each(a, function (idx, v) {
            console.log("idx %s : %s, %s, %s", idx, v[0], v[1], v[2]);
        });
  });
```

this will return

```
idx 0 : 1, 2, 3
idx 1 : 4, 5, 6
idx 2 : 7, 8, 9
idx abc : 10, 11, 12
```

Note that when you use a string as index, your data structure is an object (and not an array)

Comment: +1, did you edit the answer? I'm almost sure it was different two minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

There is no string indexed array in javascript, you need to use object.

```
        var a = {};
        a[0] = [1, 2, 3];
        a[1] = [4, 5, 6];
        a[2] = [7, 8, 9];
        a["abc"] = [10, 11, 12];

        $.each(a, function (idx, v) {

            alert("idx: " + idx);
            alert(v[0]);
            alert(v[1]);
            alert(v[2]);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery $.each iterates over an object's properties, or an array, not both. 
[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
collection: The object or array to iterate over.
```